# Dynamic underlined letters

Tags: android, xml, xamarin.android

I want to have a textview with different appearance (underline only to be exact) Can someone help how can I achieve this. I'm doing it in xamarin android.

[image: underlined letters]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `shape` to draw a line .

**1.shape_line.xml**

And you can change `android:width` and `android:height` .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <padding android:top="10dp" />
    <size
       android:width="60dp"
       android:height="10dp" />
</shape>
```

**2.Use like this .**

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
editText.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, R.drawable.shape_line);
```

**3.If you use `EditText` , you should set `android:background="@null"` .Otherwise it will have color in bottom .**

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="N"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I can't try it right now but I will definitely try it. Thanks!

Comment: Good luck to you.

Comment: It worked. Thank you!